# Magento, php foreach to string

Tags: php, string, magento, foreach

I'm using a Magento extension which sends shipments automatically to my carrier. Now I want the 'custom_id' field to be a comma separated list of the product sku's in the shipment.
**First part of the code:**

```
  $items = $myParcelShipment->getOrder()->getAllItems();
            foreach($items as $item) {
                $sku= $item->getSku();
            }
$CUSTOMLIST = [HERE A COMMA SEPARATED LIST OF PRODUCT SKU'S]
```

---

**Second part:**

```
    $data = array(
        'ToAddress'     => array(
            'name'            => trim($shippingAddress->getName()),
            'postcode'        => trim($shippingAddress->getPostcode()),
            'street'          => trim($streetData['streetname']),
            'house_number'    => trim($streetData['housenumber']),
            'town'            => $shippingAddress->getCity(),
        ),
        'ProductCode'    => $this->_getProductCodeData($myParcelShipment),
        'custom_id'      => $CUSTOMLIST,
    );
```

Any suggestions on how to transform the foreach loop into a comma separated string to be used as 'custom_id'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code

```
   $skus = array();
    $items = $myParcelShipment->getOrder()->getAllItems();
                foreach($items as $item) {
                    $skus[] = $item->getSku();
                }
    $CUSTOMLIST = implode(',', $skus);
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Now I try to replace SKU with a different custom attribute. **So i changed:** $sku= $item->getSku(); **Into:** $sku= $item->getAttributeText("afkorting"); But it does not seem to work.The attribute type is a text field, and I want to retrieve the entered text for each item. Is this possible?

Comment: try $item->getProduct()->getAttributeText("afkorting"); and please accept the answer if it works for you.